# Python - Split DataFrame to make training set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, training-data

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this called "sales_csv":

```
    id     TV  radio  newspaper  sales  invested_amount  successful_campaign
0    1  230.1   37.8       69.2   22.1        15.253394                False
1    2   44.5   39.3       45.1   10.4        12.394231                False
2    3   17.2   45.9       69.3    9.3        14.236559                False
3    4  151.5   41.3       58.5   18.5        13.583784                False
4    5  180.8   10.8       58.4   12.9        19.379845                False
```

I'm trying to split it to make a training set but it giving me this error when I run it:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [80, 78]
```

This is the code I already have:

```
# Split.
X = sales_csv.iloc[0 : 80]
y = sales_csv.iloc[81 : 159]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 5)

# Training.
gauss = GaussianNB()

gauss.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_expect = y_test
y_pred = gauss.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_expect, y_pred))
```

I'm using the rows between 0 and 160 but the DataFrame has +200 rows.

Comment: `y` should be the label column. Assuming your label column is the last one: `X = sale_csv.iloc[:, :-1]; y=sale_csv.iloc[:,-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

X is all columns but sales. And
y = df['sales'].copy()

only then you split X and y with train_split

but before that you need to labelencode your successful_campaign column - SKLEARN library have plenty of examples of above.